# Implementing a JAXBContext Resolver Class: What classes are stored in the list?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to implement a JAXBContext resolver class. What I don't understand is what types of classes are included in cTypes? I've seen several similar examples, but none explain what the cTypes list is.

```
@Provider
public class JaxbContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private final JAXBContext context;
    private final Set<Class<?>> types;
    private final Class<?>[] cTypes = {Flights.class, FlightType.class, AircraftType.class};

    public JaxbContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.types = new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(cTypes));
        this.context = new JettisonJaxbContext(JettisonConfig.DEFAULT, cTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return (types.contains(objectType)) ? context : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cTypes class list must contains all classes that represents root xml elements (Those that you annotated with @XmlRootElement).

Explanation :

When you create a JAXBContext, you give it a list of classes to bound:

```
this.context = new JettisonJaxbContext(JettisonConfig.DEFAULT, cTypes);
```

This will make JAXB able to actually associate an element with a class.
JAXB will automatically bind any classes contained in root element classes (Except the ones annotated @XmlTransient).

Then, when the getContext method is used, it will return the initialized context in your class only if the parameter class has been bound by JAXB to the said context, since your JAXBContext won't be able to use any classes that are not bound.